# Light green squash-like ingredient in Indonesian cuisine

Tags: food-identification, indonesian-cuisine

We've traveled to Indonesia years ago and there was this ingredient I had never tasted before which has had me looking for years. I had it in gado-gado many times there, including in an Indonesian restaurant in North America which had me very nostalgic!

I don't know what the original vegetable looks like but cooked, it was a pale green. I saw it served in many different shapes crescent-like, julienne, or diced, so I figure it may be some kind of squash but it didn't really taste like any squash that I know of.

Comment: Do you have any photo of the food that you ate?

Comment: It is not so interesting what it did *not* taste like; tell us what it tasted like.

Comment: Do you remember that restaurant? Ask them.

Comment: Chayote, as suggested? Raw papaya?

Comment: I tried finding a picture online and always run into cucumbers in recipes instead and it's been almost a decade, I can't describe the taste, I don't think I had a reference to relate it to!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've had gado-gado, and may other traditional indonesian salad dishes, i'm not 100% sure but could it be this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chayote

Comment: This looks like it! I'll try to find one and cook but by the pictures I'm seeing in recipes, I'm almost 100% sure. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is Chayote because they are famous for not having any taste , in Australia apparently they use Chayote (called choko) in McDonalds Apple Pies as the "apple pieces".

If it has flavour, and if it is not coming from the sauce/seasoning of what it is with, then maybe it some sort of egg plant? They come in all different shapes and sizes and this does have a nice flavour and some types can be eaten raw in salad etc I believe like papaya?

Comment: It was subtle but did have flavor. Not so much if covered in sauce from what I recall. What type of eggplant would be more likely to be found in these part? It held its shape without problem and looked sort of like finger sized pieces of honeydew melon.